# How to count total zeros according to criteria of another column of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

For a school activity to identify sensors in datasets that are working, I have the following dataframe:

```
      # Import library
      import pandas as pd
      import numpy as np

      # Define dataframe
      df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['21F', '21F', '21F', '21F', '2H', '2H',
                                '2H', '2H', 'H5', 'H5', 'H5', 'H5'],
                         'Value': [0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 0],
                         'Column_n': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]})
      print(df)

      ID    Value   Column_n
     21F    0         0
     21F    0         1
     21F    0         2
     21F    255       3
     2H     255       4
     2H     255       5
     2H     0         6
     2H     0         7
     H5     255       8
     H5     255       9
     H5     255       10
     H5     0         11
```

Note: The value = 0 means that the sensor is valid, but the value = 255 means that the sensor is invalid.

The rule is if the amount of 'Value' = 0 is greater than or equal to 2, then the sensor is valid.

I thought of saving the valid and invalid sensor ID list as follows:

```
      # Create an array ID unique
      array_id_unique = np.array(df['ID'].unique())


      list_id_VALID = []
      list_id_INVALID = []

      for i in range(0, len(array_id_unique)):   
           id_curr = array_id_unique[i]

           df_curr = df[df['ID'] == id_curr]


           if(len(df_curr[df_curr['Value'] == 0]) >= 2):      
               list_id_VALID.append(id_curr)        
          else:
               list_id_INVALID.append(id_curr)
```

The code is working, but it takes a while. Is there another way to replace the iteration with for()?

Outputs:
print(list_id_VALID)
> ['21F', '2H']

```
           print(list_id_VALID)
           > ['H5']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use vectorial code with [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) and booleans:

```
valid_sensors = df['Value'].eq(0).groupby(df['ID']).sum().ge(2)

out = valid_sensors.index[valid_sensors].tolist()
```

Or with [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
valid_sensors = df.loc[df['Value'].eq(0), 'ID'].value_counts().ge(2)

valid_sensors.index[valid_sensors].tolist()
```

Output: `['21F', '2H']`

Comment: Worked perfectly! The code ran much faster than the previous one. Thanks.